# Slim 3 autoloader

Tags: php, autoload, slim

I'm new to slim framework, and can't figure out how to use the autoloader to autoload my classes.

I created a `app/models/myclass.php`  but of course when I try to use it I get a class not found. I'm not sure which is the right way to autoload classes, or the naming convensions I should use. Should I do it via the composer.json somehow? I'm searching the net for several hours without any solid answer on that.

**UPDATE**:

Managed to do it like that:

- added model in : app/src/Model/Client.php
- added `namespace App\Model;` in Client.php
- added the following in depedencies.php:

```php
$container['App\Model\Client'] = function ($c) {
    return new App\Model\Client();
};
```

and routes.php:

```php
$app->get('/client/ping/{id}',  function ($request, $response, $args)  {
    $container = $this->getContainer();
    $client=$container['App\Model\Client']; //instantiates a new Client
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need `use ($app)` in Slim 3 since you can call `$this` to get the App.

Comment: You're right, thanks I will update the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For autoloading of own classes you should use `Composer` by adding some options to your `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "My\\Namespace\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

```php
// index.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App();
$myClass = new \My\Namespace\MyClass();
```

After running `composer update` composer will register your own namespaces and will autoload them for you.

Comment: It is already included. Then what? How do I configure it for my models?

Comment: This is about slim 3, I believe the model class should be added somewhere in the container.

Comment: Must not but can. Does your code above work? If still getting error try to add leading backslash before instatiation: `return new \App\Model\Client();`

Comment: sorry I didn't use your answer, it seems Slim 3 installed through the composer already has an autoloader for app/src. I believe your answer was for Slim2. I just placed my class on the correct path.

Comment: Composer can't autoload your files when you don't specify it or register some autoloader that knows where to search for files. Where you got this info?

Comment: I figured it out. I installed slim 3 with composer require slim/slim:~3.0@dev

Comment: Fresh installation? And then require composers autoloader - not more?

Comment: Yes fresh installation, no other composer configuration. composer.json already included an ""App\\": "app/src"" autoload section.

Comment: When you copied the [Slim3 Skeleton](https://github.com/akrabat/slim3-skeleton) of course there is this autoload, because @Akrabat do autoloading the same way like me.. Look into composer.json - it's the same autoloading.

Comment: Well, as I said before I didn't use it because it was not a composer configuration issue, it was a path thing. But since I was not clear in my question I will approve as it might help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in composer.json file
Where app1 is the name of the folder you want to Autoload.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4":{
        "app1\\": "anything"
    }
}
```

After doing this run this in cmd (via composer)

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```