# Calling a method form a .class.php file (slim framework)

Tags: php, class, methods, slim

I am using the Slim framework for the development of a web-app.
However, I came across some issues which I can not solve.

I want organize my code in classes and call certain methods from the classes.
i have an index.php file in which the following function exists:

```
$app->post('/',  function () use ($app) {
// some code here
//a variable  $result I want to get the result from a method of the    class Generate_num
$result = (here I want it to take as a result the function "generate"     from a .class.php file which I have stored in a special folder "classes"
 //another code
});
```

my class code looks like this

```
class Generate_num
{
public static function generate()
 {
//some code
 }
}
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you !

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500702/slim-3-autoloader

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this class:

```
class Generate_num
{
    public static function generate()
    {
        //some code that creates $number
        return $number;
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
$number = Generate_num::generate();
```